# Permutation in which the $A's$ appear together in a block of $4$ letters or the $B's$ appear together in a block of $3$ letters

Tags: combinatorics

The number of permutation of all the letters $AAAABBBC$ in which the $A's$ appear together in a block of $4$ letters or the $B's$ appear together in a block of $3$ letters is :
$(A)44\hspace{1cm}(B)50\hspace{1cm}(C)60\hspace{1cm}(D)89$

---

I let the $A's$ as a single entity and $B's$ as another single entity,So there are three entities.So total permutations are $3!$.But there is no such option,I am wrong somewhere.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: The question asks how many permutations have the A's as a block *or* the B's as a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the principle of inclusion and exclusion. Let $S_A$ represent the number of instances where $A$ appears together as a single entity, $S_B$ represent the number of instances where $B$ appears together as a single entity, and $S_{AB}$ represent the number of instances where both appear as a single entity. Then your required answer, the number of instances where either of them can appear as a single entity, is $S_A + S_B - S_{AB} = \frac{5!}{3!} + \frac{6!}{4!} - 3! = 20 + 30 - 6 = 44$.

Note that you found the answer for both events occurring together, which is the "and" case - not the "or" case.